# While appending a list over other list, getting empty list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

code:

```
def merge_the_tools(string, k):
slist=list(string.strip())
subs=[]
full_subs=[]
for i in range(0,len(string),k):
    for j in range(i,i+k):
        subs.append(slist[j])
    print(subs)
    full_subs.append(subs)
    subs.clear()
    print(full_subs)
```

input:
string:AABCAAADA
k:3

output:
['A', 'A', 'B']
[[]]         #expected [['A', 'A', 'B']] 
['C', 'A', 'A']
[[], []]     #expected [['A', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'A']]
['A', 'D', 'A']
[[], [], []] #expected [['A', 'A', 'B'],['C', 'A', 'A'],['A', 'D', 'A']]

As you can see in the above code, I'm trying to make a list of lists. But every time the list gets appended to the new list, its forming an empty list of lists. I really can't figure out what's going on here. Please help me out.

Comment: Of course it's empty. You explicitly clear it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Any suggestions on what other way would help me here, please?  edit: nvm. reinitializing the list helped me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subs.clear(), I used subs=[]. Now the code is working as intended.

Answer (score -2):

```
def merge_the_tools(string, k):

    slist=list(string) # здесь просто из строки делается список
    print(slist)
    sub=[]
    full_sub=[]
    for i in range(0, len(string), k):
        sub.clear()
        for j in range(i, i+k):
            sub.append(slist[j])
        full_sub.append(sub)
        print(full_sub)
```

Is it OK?

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or another question? Please take the [tour] and read [answer].